# Filter/Map/Reduce properly

Tags: javascript, mapping, filtering, reduce

I'm trying to filter a users JSON via JavaScript's `filter`, `map`, and `reduce` methods. However I cannot get the exact result I pretend.

```
var users = {
"fooUser": {
  "apps": [
    {
      "id": "7i2j3bk85"
    },
    {
      "id": "o8yasg69h"
    }
  ]
},
"barUser": {
  "apps": [
    {
      "id": "789gbiai7t"
    }
  ]
}};
```

The logic is: I only know the AppId (and not the User it belogs to), so I'd have to map/filter each User, and return it ONLY if it has that Appid (and return ONLY that AppId).

```
var filteredApps = Object.keys(users).filter(function (element, index, array) {

  var exists = users[element].apps.filter(function (element, index, array) {

    if (element.id === 'o8yasg69h') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (exists[0]) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}).map(function (item, index, array) {
  return users[item].apps;
});

console.log(filteredApps);
```

I obtain (a multiArray with no-filtered Apps):

```
[[
  {
    id: "7i2j3bk85"
  },
  {
    id: "o8yasg69h"
  }
]]
```

But I would like to obtain (one plain Object, with the filtered App):

```
{
  id: "o8yasg69h"
}
```

Comment: _"BUT I would like to obtain (one plain Object, with the filtered App):"_ Is expected result an object with a single property ?

Comment: To get `exists` I think you should use `.some()` instead of `.filter()`.

Comment: for just checking for existance of `'o8yasg69h'` value in the object - the above code is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following one-liner:

```
[].concat(...Object.keys(users).map(x=> users[x].apps)).find(x=> x.id === "o8yasg69h")
```

To expand it a bit:

```
[].concat(...                    // flattens the array of apps
  Object.keys(users)             // gets the keys of users
   .map(x=> users[x].apps)       // maps the array to the apps of the user
).find(x=> x.id === "o8yasg69h") // finds app which id is "o8yasg69h"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with `reduce` and ES6 `find`:

```
function searchById(id){
    return Object.keys(users).reduce(function(result, user){
        return result ? result : users[user].apps.find(function(obj){
            return obj.id === id;
        });
    }, false);
}
```